# AJAX jQuery click results in function event being fired twice

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal

I have an AJAX chat room module in Drupal and I am trying to insert BBCode stlye `tex` tags to the submit box when the user clicks `Insert Tex`. I managed to get the following code to work the first time but afterwards when I click `Insert Tex` it inserts the `tex` tags triple times.

```
$('#edit-chatroom-message-entry-submit').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  if ($('#edit-chatroom-message-entry-box').val()){
    Drupal.chatroom.postMessage($('#edit-chatroom-message-entry-box').val());
    $('#edit-chatroom-message-entry-box').val('').focus();
  }
});

$('#edit-chatroom-tex-submit').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('#edit-chatroom-message-entry-box').val($('#edit-chatroom-message-entry-box').val() + '[tex][/tex]');
});
```

I would appreciate it if a suggestion could be make to make the code work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the caret position to 0 in jquery fixed the problem: caret(0);

Comment: Adding a drawing canvas I came across this same problem again in a different setting. Setting the caret position to 0 in jquery fixed the problem:

       caret(0);

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your code you need this:

```
var chatbox = $('#edit-chatroom-message-entry-box');
var value = chatbox.val();

if (value.indexOf('[tex][/tex]') == -1) {
    chatbox.val(value + '[tex][/tex]');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ivo but I was not able to get your code to work. I deleted the last line of my second function and added your code but I am still seeing double tags. If I click again then I see triple tags...and so on. Can you suggest anything else? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, the url is `http://sharpermath.com/drupal/node/24` I'm sure you can use firebug to to test it